# Trouble with print led program

Tags: c++

Its suppose to princh each time the led blinks in the serial plotter/command box
like
1
2
3
4
5
but it only shows 10 the total blinks

```
int ledPin = 11;
int blinkTime = 700;
int timesBlinked = 0;
 

void setup()
{
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
  blinkyBlinky(10, blinkTime); // 10 is number of blinks, blinkTime is the milliseconds in each state from above: int blinkTime = 500;
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print(timesBlinked, DEC);
  timesBlinked++; 
  
  Serial.setTimeout(500);
  
}

void loop()
{
 
  
  
}

void blinkyBlinky(int repeats, int time){
  
  for (int i = 0; i < repeats; i++)
  {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    delay(500);
    Serial.println(timesBlinked, DEC);
    timesBlinked++; 
  }
}
```

for command has to be used

Answer (score 1):

You called

```
blinkyBlinky(10, blinkTime);
```

before

```
Serial.begin(9600);
```

You can't write with

```
Serial.println(timesBlinked, DEC);
```

before

```
Serial.begin(9600);
```

was called.

Swap the lines in `setup`:

```
void setup()
{
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  blinkyBlinky(10, blinkTime); // 10 is number of blinks, blinkTime is the milliseconds in each state from above: int blinkTime = 500;
  Serial.print(timesBlinked, DEC);
  timesBlinked++; 
  
  Serial.setTimeout(500);
  
}
```

Comment: Jesus christ ty so much I've been on stuck on this for hours and it was that simple ugh